# Binding variable in Scheme not knowing how many variables you have

Tags: scheme

I'm looking for a way to search , using an pattern in Scheme . Like , if I have a search pattern

```
'((x likes  y) (y is a hard sport) (x is rich))
```

and the input

```
'((Mike likes rugby) (Rachel likes tennis) 
  (rugby is a hard sport ) ( tennis is easy)
  (Mike is rich) (Rachel is rich))
```

I Should only get Mike as he's the only one that qualifies for every restrictions .

I've been trying to do this for hours . I've been trying to bind x first to Mike , then use Mike instead of x everywhere . Problem is, I don't know how many variables I have , is there a way to do this or my idea is totally wrong?

Comment: Do you have an actual example of exactly what you're trying to accomplish? It's a little vague currently

Comment: Sure , sorry for that .I want to define a function that will search after a pattern I will give it . Say I had the pattern '((x likes  y) (y is a hard sport) (x is rich)) as 'search' and '((Mike likes rugby) (Rachel likes tennis) 
  (rugby is a hard sport ) ( tennis is easy)
  (Mike is rich) (Rachel is rich))  as 'data'. I wanna make (pattern-match search data ) that will return Mike (in this case)

Comment: You're going to have to provide something identifying exactly what the variables are. Otherwise it's not clear that say `rugby` isn't a variable. (To us sure, but less so to scheme)

Comment: well first x binds to Mike , then y binds to rugby (this is because of (x likes y) . So now I will search for (rugby is a hard sport) . If I don't find this in the input 'data'-> I go back to x and bind it to Rachel this time , then y will bind to tennis....and so on till I find the correct match.

Comment: I have a problem with that "back". How can I go back and say , x ain't binded to Mike anymore because search failed , try x bind to Rachel this time. Also , I have x and y here , I could have n variables without me knowing how many so a let at the start wont do it ( Atleast I cannot find how)

Comment: But how do you know what whats a variable and what isn't, you don't want to substitute for every single honking work because it's crazy inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is fairly classic [logic programming](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node92.html). The approach I've always used for Scheme is some variant on the `amb` operator.

`amb` works like this:

```
(let ((x (amb 1 2 3 4))
      (y (amb 5 6 7 8))
   (rule (= 10 (+ x y))
   (list x y))
```

which will return some `x y` so that their sum is 10. Now using this and some other witchcraft we can make your system.

Firstly the pattern is going to be our "rules". So let's say we format our pattern like this:

```
'((list-of-vars) (rule 1) (rule 2) (rule 3))
```

Now for our input data, let's say it's structured like this:

```
'((list-of-values) (fact 1) (fact 2) (fact 3))
```

Now our life becomes pretty easy, we just want to have our scheme macro/procedure/witchcraft do something like this:

```
(define-syntax resolve
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ ((v1 vs ...)
         r1 rs ...)
        ((ps ...)
     f1 fs ...))
     (let* ((v1 (amb ps ...))
           (vs (amb ps ...))
           ...
           (sym-table (list (cons (quote v1) v1)
                            (cons (quote vs) vs)
                        ...))
           (facts '(f1 fs ...))
           (rules '(r1 rs ...)))
       (map rule (map
                  (lambda (rule)
                    (member (substitute rule sym-table)
                            facts))
                  rules))
       sym-table)]))
```

[full code in a gist](https://gist.github.com/jozefg/5190455)

Hopefully this gives you a starting point, let me know what questions you have.

Comment: First , thanks :D. Now , if I understood you correctly , you are using let , so you need to know how many variables you have . This is my biggest problem .  In my example I had x and y , but I could have n variables , what then? is there a way to "expand" the let block? First bind x , then y , then z.....etc or I'm doomed?

Comment: Thats what the macro is for, im not kidding you can actually tell it to expand like that. Im just hacking out something similar to show you

Comment: No problems, if you find any answer here helpful, you can check the green check beside it to mark it as answered

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to need an unknown number of variables, use an [association list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_list) or a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for storing name-value bindings, Scheme provides built-in procedures for dealing with both data structures.

The problem description and the kind of matching required look a lot like a job for [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) or a similar [logic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming) system. If you're stuck using Scheme, consider implementing the [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29#Unification_in_logic_programming) algorithm (as shown in [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node92.html)), or using a logic programming system embedded in Scheme, for instance [KANREN](http://kanren.sourceforge.net/) or [miniKANREN](http://kanren.sourceforge.net/#mini). And while we're at it, you should also check [The Reasoned Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262562146) for reference.